# Why specify same port in sin_port in both server and client?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I am learning Socket-programming in C++. I understand that the socket must bind to the server address and in the client side, there is an internal `bind()` when `connect()` is called. The server listens on the port specified in `sin_port` of the `struct sockaddr_in`.

But when I specify the same port to `sin_port` of the `struct sockaddr_in` in client, does that mean that both client and server are bound on the same port. I hope this is the part, I am going wrong.

Here are the codes :

SERVER :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int sockid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockid<0){
        cout<<"failed socket";
    }
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int cz=sizeof(client);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(9999);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(bind(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server))<0){
        cout<<"Failed binding";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"binded\n";

    if(listen(sockid,3)<0){//
        cout<<"\nFailed Listening";
        return 0;
    }

    int client_socket=accept(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t*)&cz);

    if(client_socket<0){
        cout<<"Failed connecting";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Connected....\n";

    char buff[1024]={0};

    cout<<"enter message: ";
    cin>>buff;
    if(send(client_socket,buff,strlen(buff),0)<0){
        cout<<"\nFailed sending\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Message sent";




    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT

```
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int sockid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockid<0){
        cout<<"failed socket";
    }
    struct sockaddr_in  client;

    int cz=sizeof(client);
    client.sin_family=AF_INET;
    client.sin_port=htons(9999);
    client.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;




    int server_socket=connect(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client));

    if(server_socket<0){
        cout<<"Failed connecting";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Connected\n";

    char buff[250];//

    recv(sockid,buff,1024,0);
    cout<<"Received msg: "<<buff;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server should `bind` to the same port the client `connect`s to. That way, the server and client will be talking to each other. Typically, the server `bind`s to a well-known port and `listen`s. The client doesn't call `bind`, which results in it binding to a random port. But it does call `connect` to connect to the server's well-known port. The server listens on, sends from, and receives on the well-known port. The client connects to, sends to, and receives from the well-known port.

Also, don't actually ever do this:

```
recv(sockid,buff,1024,0);
cout<<"Received msg: "<<buff;
```

TCP is not a message-based protocol. The `recv` function, when called on a TCP socket, does *not* receive a message nor even know what a message is. When you call a stream's `operator<<` and pass it a `char *`, like you are, it expects that `char *` to point to a valid C-style string, which is not assured in this code. Worse, you've ignored the return value from `recv` which is the *only* way to know how many bytes you received.

There's a similar issue here:

```
if(send(client_socket,buff,strlen(buff),0)<0){
```

You don't send the terminating zero byte, so there is no way for the receiver to figure out where the message ends other than by the fact that you then close the connection. This works only in the exact case where you want to send precisely one message and then close the connection without any possibility of a response. And, in this case, the receiver needs to keep calling `recv` until it gets an indication that the connection has been closed before it considers itself to have received a message.

Comment: Yes, I understand that after reading many SO answers but what  I don't understand is why keeping the same port no. for sin_port same. What does sin_port mean here ?

Comment: Also its normal practice for the listener to spawn another process on a random port number -- all further traffic goes to the spawned process using the anonymous port number. Leaving the listener free to allow other clients to connect.

Comment: @JamesAnderson I find that saying things like that tends to confuse people. All of the listener's connections are to the same port and all of the listener's transmissions are from the same port.

Comment: @George It means different things on both sides. On one side, it's part of the information passed to `bind`, so it controls the port the server binds to. On the other side, it's part of the information passed to `connect`, so it controls the port the client connects to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's what I wanted to hear. But, does that also mean that the `sin_addr.s_addr` in server side means the IP address on which the server listens and in the client side it means the IP address to connect to, which should always be the IP address of the server.

Comment: @George Yes, since that is setting what is passed to `bind` in the server and what is passed to `connect` in the client, it too should specify what the server should bind to and what the client should connect to.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Add this detail mentioned by you in your answer for the sake of completeness. !!

Comment: @George Honestly, I think it makes the answer more confusing. It's clear from the code that `server` and `client` are two different `sockaddr_in` structures and the answer already states in the first paragraph that the server calls `bind` and the client calls `connect`. If you think it can be done in a non-confusing way, feel free to propose an edit.